# PHP Form - File upload not working

Tags: javascript, php, forms, file-upload

Trying to allow file upload along with a form that is otherwise working. I cut out the relevant form/input/processing rules. Hopefully someone who is more than ankle-deep in PHP (as I am) can point me in the right direction?

```html
<form name="form-quote" id="form-quote" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['../WPTheme/REQUEST_URI' . '#form-quote'] ?>" method="POST">

  <div class="form_labels">
    <p><label for="fileupload">Upload File (optional):</label></p>
  </div>
  <div class="form_inputs">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5242880" />
    <p><input type="file" name="fileupload" id="fileupload" accept=".pdf, .txt, .rtf, .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx" style="margin-bottom:2px;"/>
    <span style="color:#777;">(pdf, txt, rtf, doc, docx, xls, xlsx, &lt;5MB)</span></p>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="formtype" id="formtype-quote" value="quote">

  <div class="form_labels submit">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>

  <div class="form_inputs">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="action" class="btn-red" ></a>
  </div>

</form>

<?php
//$formerrors is set to false unless one of the validation rules for the OTHER fields fails - no validation on the file upload, although I would like to trim & sanitize it if possible.

if (!($formerrors) && isset($_POST['fileupload'])):
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["fileupload"]["temp_name"];
    $uploadfilename = $_FILES["fileupload"]["name"];
    $savedate = date("mdy-Hms");
    $newfilename = "/wp-content/uploads_forms/" . $savedate . "_" . $uploadfilename;
    $uploadurl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $newfilename;
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $newfilename)):
        $msg = "File uploaded.";
    else: 
        $msg = "Sorry, your file could not be uploaded." . $_FILES['file']['error'];
        $formerrors = true;
    endif; //move uploaded file
endif;

?>
```

Thanks to Alexander's answer below, I was able to modify my validator to work and to achieve my original goals (check for null, and give files unique names before uploading). Here's my "final draft," which is working now.

```html
//Check form errors, check file name not null, rename file with unique identifier to avoid overwriting existing files with same name

if (!($formerrors)) {
  $tmp_file = $_FILES["fileupload"]["tmp_name"];
  if ($tmp_file != "") {
    $savedate = date("mdy-Hms");
    $target_dir = "wp-content/uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . $savedate . '_' . $_FILES["fileupload"]["name"];
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $target_file)) {
      $msg = "File uploaded.";
    } else { 
      $msg = "Sorry, your file could not be uploaded.";
      $formerrors = true;
    }//move successful
  }//end null check
}//end form errors check
```

Comment: PHP is not JS. It seems like you're going to want an AJAX approach. `<?php` or `<?` (if short tags enabled) starts a PHP block, not `<script>`. Also PHP isn't available once the page has loaded.

Comment: Sorry - script tags changed to PHP. Just mistyped when copying the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are using above is Javascript. In case you depend on that please change the tags of the post. If not here is a possibility for a PHP-Uploadscript:

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileupload"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileupload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileupload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

SOURCE: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

EDIT: The script above has be placed in the file receiving the POST from the form.

Comment: This was very helpful -- thanks. As a newbie, just seeing something written in a different way helps me understand it better. Your code, on its own, will throw an error if the file upload field is null (in my form, the upload is optional), and it will also overwrite files on the server if they have the same name (like "resume.doc"). So with new understanding from your code, I cobbled together a hybrid that achieves those two things for me. I will add my final code to the original question. This was a great learning experience -- thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is a big mess!
Let's try to clarify some basic points...

**File-upload mechanism**

For file-upload to work you must have a `<form>` with `action` attribute addressing the script where you'll check and use the uploaded file.
This script *may* be the same as the one where the `<form>` is generated, assumed you take care of the pitfalls that come with this situation.

At a first general glance your current code seems to correspond to the latter case.
But your form `action` looks weird:

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['../WPTheme/REQUEST_URI' . '#form-quote'] ?>"
```

As a first intent, if you want to address the same page where you already are, you can simply omit `action` attribute.
Here you seem to explicitely try the same, adding the precision of `#form-quote`, but:

- This `#form-quote` has no effect here, since such a hash is made to target a `<a>`, while it's currently affected to your `<form>`.
- The other part of the url you build is a non-sense mixing `REQUEST_URI` (which is the *name* of one of the `$_SERVER` members) with the hard-core expression of a path in your context.
- Anyway all the above doesn't matter, because this end with `$_SERVER[...something which is not a known $_SERVER member...]`, so it actually returns `NULL`, and somewhat ironically it has the same effect as if you didn't specify `action` at all!

**PHP in a SO snippet**

So ou put your code in a snippet, but SO snippets work only with HTML, CSS, and Javascript, so you can't expect it allows to demonstrate how your code is working or not.

Note that at this step, despite the errors mentioned above, we didn't point something which would make your code to fail.
*And in your question you didn't mention how it fails!*

**Uploaded file processing**

So looking at your PHP code part, I first note this statement:

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES["fileupload"]["temp_name"];
```

where you're looking for `temp_name`, while the true involved key is `tmp_name`. This alone is enough to make your code to fail.

Furthermore looking at these two statements:

```
$uploadurl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $newfilename;
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $newfilename))
```

In the 1st one you use `$newfilename` as the complement of the url you're building, so obviously `$newfilename` can't target an *absolute physical* path.
It means that in the 2nd one you try to `move_uploaded_file()` to a wrong place!

Last point, you currently don't take care of possible errors before trying to use the uploaded file.
You should complete your primary condition like this:

```
if (!($formerrors) && isset($_POST['fileupload'])) && !$_FILES["fileupload"]["error"])
```

And if you effectively get some errors and have trouble to understand why, you should also look at [this interesting PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php).

Comment: Sorry for not posting the whole form -- it's long and elaborate. (From a Lynda.com tutorial, so the methods aren't mine...I don't have any methods yet!) I thought it best to focus on the relevant parts, and seeing Alexander's code helped me right the ship.  *YOU ARE RIGHT* that I have a couple of typos in my original code that may have been the main reason it wasn't working. I used "temp_name" instead of "tmp_name" and I also had a leading slash in my target directory that shouldn't have been.  Thanks for your review & input. I have much to learn and I appreciate everyone's help in this forum.